# Trying to transfer big file docker container Error response from daemon: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout: stderr: unexpected EOF

Tags: docker

Hi im trying to transfer the bitcoin blockchain files into my docker container, I can docker cp the files no problem into my docker container but when i commit the changes into the docker image i get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: unexpected EOF
```

The folder is about 80gb in size. What do i have to do to get this to work?

docker info:

```
Containers: 8
Images: 8
Storage Driver: btrfs
Build Version: Btrfs v4.2.2
Library Version: 101
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 4.6.0-1-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux stretch/sid (containerized)
CPUs: 6
Total Memory: 15.59 GiB
Name: debian
ID: UV2L:CG6Y:NQ4W:K7KY:6VN5:DIMN:SYED:BIQK:ZYBZ:HH4I:NE5Y:4ACN
Username: hamiltino
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Comment: Is it an inode issue? (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11079#issuecomment-169437042) Or en environment one? (https://github.com/deis/deis/issues/2723#issuecomment-203603804)

Comment: I'm running on my local computer, using hardisk, switching to ssd now to see if it helps with the heavy load.

Comment: Now i get a new error: input/output error.... I'm going to see if i can split the file to smaller chunks and transfer them one at a time to the container.

Comment: @HashTables - did you managed to pull it off ?